# How to trigger email after 2 days ? (i have tried it with sleep() but it is delaying the all page script.) I only want to delay the mail function

Tags: dreamweaver

$subject="Application Enquiry Details";

$to="$email";

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";

//$headers .= "Cc:Webmaster\r\n";

$headers .= "From: noreply \r\n";

$message="your application is recieved";

sleep(60);

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

Comment: I think it would be best to queue those emails before sending. That is either insert into a table (with send-time as one column to later select from) or use some other queueing mechanism.

Then you'll need something (like a cron job) to run a second script that will then pull the records to be sent from the queue (= table), send them and remove from the queue.

Answer (score 1):

As Jan said, you should maintain a queue in database. Set a cron job which should run a script. This script should traverse the table looking for an email to send.

I'll suggest instead of removing record from table, maintain a flag to indicate it's done. So this table will work as queue and log too.